# asp.net how to change a control which is in parent master page, from content page with nested master pages

Tags: asp.net, attributes, nested, master-pages, web-controls

I have ParentMaster.master, Child1Master.master, Child2Master.master and several content pages under both 2 child masters.
In the parent master I have controls (buttons and labels) residing **outside** of the asp:ContentPlaceHolder.
I need to change the text of the buttons and labels in the ParentMaster (2 levels up) from within the code behind of the content pages. I also need to change the 'visible' attribute of these controls to false or true.

The only thing I managed up to now was to change (from a content page) the text of a label in a 1-level Master, say from 'AAAA' to 'BBBB', like this :

In Master1.Master :

```
<li><asp:label ID="lbl_something" runat="server" Text="AAAA"></asp:label></li>
```

In Master1.Master.cs :

```
public string str_In_Master
{
    get
    {
        return lbl_something.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        lbl_something.Text = value;
    }
    }
```

In the content page :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Master.str_In_Master = "BBBB";
}
```

**But this wouldn't work in a nested master pages situations**.

Can it be done at all? Can I change attributes of controls in the top-level MasterPage, including 'Text' and 'Visible'?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can access parent master from content page like this.

```
        var childMater1 = this.Master;
        var parentMater = childMater1.Master;
```

u can access any public property of parent master.

```
        var childMater1 = this.Master;
        var parentMater = childMater1.Master;
        var typedMaster = parentMater as ParentMaster;
        typedMaster.SomeProperty = "some value";
```

u can access any control of ParentMaster.

```
        var childMater1 = this.Master;
        var parentMater = childMater1.Master;
        var label = parentMater.FindControl("someLabelId") as Label;
        label.Text = "new label value";
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Both worked though only in Page_Load of the content page. Doesn't work in the "OnClick" part of a button. I'll look for a way to that too. (marked it as an answer and thanks again!)